# GCC error - cannot execute binary file

Tags: gcc

**[Thank you everyone!., sorry i didn't see the mismatched kernel, for some reason i was thinking this was my ubuntu server 64 bit]**

I compiled a custom gcc tool chain using ct-ng, compilation was successful but i wrote a simple hello world and i see this error

Could someone, please point me what is wrong here and why i get this error?

**Error:**

```
src/main$ ./main 
bash: ./main: cannot execute binary file
```

About **OS**

```
uname -a
Linux lnx-server 3.2.0-25-generic-pae #40-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 23 22:11:24 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Some **additional info** on the file

```
src/main$ file main
main: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, not stripped
```

**File permission**

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 balravin balravin  8276 Jul 27 17:45 main
```

**Command** used to compile

```
src/main$ x86_64-mvl-linux-gnu-gcc -o main main2.c
```

**GCC configuration**

> ```
> > src/main$ x86_64-mvl-linux-gnu-gcc --v Using built-in specs. Target:
> > x86_64-mvl-linux-gnu Configured with:
> > /home/balravin/tools/platform/x86/src/gnu/gcc/4.2.4/.build/src/gcc-4.2.4/configure
> > --build=i686-build_pc-linux-gnu --host=i686-build_pc-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-mvl-linux-gnu --prefix=/home/balravin/tools/platform/x86/obj/gnu/gcc/4.2.4/x86_64-mvl-linux-gnu
> > --with-sysroot=/home/balravin/tools/platform/x86/obj/gnu/gcc/4.2.4/x86_64-mvl-linux-gnu/x86_64-mvl-linux-gnu/sysroot
> > --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-libmudflap --enable-libgomp --enable-libssp --enable-threads=posix --enable-target-optspace --with-long-double-128 --disable-nls --disable-multilib --with-local-prefix=/home/balravin/tools/platform/x86/obj/gnu/gcc/4.2.4/x86_64-mvl-linux-gnu/x86_64-mvl-linux-gnu/sysroot
> > --enable-c99 --enable-long-long Thread model: posix gcc version 4.2.4
> ```

And **finally** main2.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {

    printf("\nHello Work\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to run a 64-bit executable on a 32-bit OS.  Either install a 64-bit OS, or rebuild your compiler to produce 32-bit executables.

Answer (score 4):

Your kernel is 32-bit, and you have compiled a 64-bit binary.  You need a 64-bit kernel on 64-bit hardware in order to run a 64-bit binary.